# git diff <branch> shows difference between a/File b/File. Which is a and which is b?

Tags: git

I have a `master` branch and a `foo` branch. Neither branch has anything to commit but they have diverged from one another. I am in `foo` branch and I run

```
git diff master
```

I get the following output

```
diff --git a/myfile.html b/myfile.html
index 48d09a1..4ced8e5 100644
--- a/AdvancedSearch.aspx
+++ b/AdvancedSearch.aspx
@@ -1919,1 +1919,2 @@
     </script>

-Line removed in master or foo - I don't know which 
+Line added in master or foo - I don't know which
```

Is the new line added in `master` or in `foo`? Is the old line removed in `master` or in `foo`? How can I tell?

Also what about this situation? I am on branch `bar` and I want to see the difference between `master` and `foo`:

```
git status
On branch bar    
nothing added to commit, working directory clean

git diff master..foo
```

When I have made changes in my working tree and then run `git diff` it is obvious what has changed. But when doing it between different branches I am struggling to read the diffs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For`git diff <commit>`:

- `a`/`-` represents `<commit>`
- `b`/`+` represents the current working tree

For`git diff <commit1> <commit2>`:

- `a`/`-` represents `<commit1>`
- `b`/`+` represents `<commit2>`

Reading `git diff`:

`git diff` finds the changes required to turn `<commit1>`into `<commit2>`/working-tree. So:

- Non-highlighted: lines are common between the two commits
- `-`: lines **in** `<commit1>`, but **not** in `<commit2>`/working-tree

  - ie. the lines that need to be removed to turn `<commit1>` into `<commit2>`
- `+`: lines **not** in `<commit1>`, but **in** `<commit2>`/working-tree

  - ie. lines that needs to be added to `<commit1>`

Edit:

You can also make git use mnemonic prefixes instead of `a` and `b`. See [git documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/diff-config#Documentation/diff-config.txt-diffmnemonicPrefix) for details.

Answer (score 0):

Be explicit about which revisions you are interested in and note that the git-diff manual says

> However, "diff" is about comparing two endpoints, not ranges, and the range notations (".." and "...") do not mean a range as defined in the "SPECIFYING RANGES" section in gitrevisions(7).

If you cannot find the revision number for the commits that interest you, you've got bigger problems. Thus:

```
$ git diff ccd55fe cb3e8a0
```

where revision ccd55fe is the "a" side and cb3e8a0 is the "b" side. Correspondingly, the command

```
$ git diff cb3e8a0 ccd55fe
```

is the exact inverse, and again, there is no ambiguity between "a left-side" and "b right-side".